# How can I compile a .scss file directly onto my server using atom with sass-autocompile plugin

Tags: css, sass, atom-editor, auto-compile

I'm having an issue compiling my .scss file into .css.

I am using Atom with the sass-autocompile plugin and compile on save is enabled.
I can access and read the files from the sidebar, but when I save/compile my .scss file, I get this error message:

> "status": 3,
>     "message": "File to read not found or unreadable: /run/user/1000/gvfs/ftp:host=ftp.**********.de,user=*****-admin/path/css/complement.scss",
>     "formatted": "Internal Error: File to read not found or unreadable: /run/user/1000/gvfs/ftp:host=ftp.*********.de,user=*****-admin/path/complement.scss\n"

Any idea as why I'm getting this error, or how I can go around it and get to work on my .scss directly on the server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Few info to answer. Try to start new project and add only single `.scss` file.

Comment: Hi! I tried that but didn't do any difference. What infos would you need for a more complete answer?

Comment: Your os, link to plugin you are using. Also you maybe you can try other plugins?

Comment: I'm on linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia and I'm using the [sass-autocompile] (https://atom.io/packages/sass-autocompile) plugin. And yes I've tried a few others, they all give me an error

Comment: Same error?
I just cant uderstand that line
`/run/user/1000/gvfs/ftp:host=ftp.**********.de,user=*****-admin/path/css/complement.scss"`, 

Looks like some script is trying to get something using ftp looks ver wierd.

Comment: I agree! I'll try to complete the picture: I've ste up a ftp connection to my server using the linux file browser. I'm no expert, but i seems that the ftp programm created a file in /run/user/1000 etc. to access the data, or have some kind of a download/upload dynamic every time I access modify a file. Does it make sens?

Comment: Are you trying to modify some file on your server using Atom editor on your local computer?

Comment: Yes. It does work for other files. It's just the compiling part that doesn't work

Comment: Yes I believe plugin asumes that file is in your local machine. It makes all more complicate in taht case and I afraid I can't help to solve that problem. Only one thing: are you sure it is a right way to work with your files? Usually programmers work on local machines and use git to deliver changes to server.